# Why do CSS Margin Collapse?

Tags: css

I understand that sometimes the vertical margins can collapse, what I don't understand is why they chose this behavior in the W3C specs.

I can only see this being useful when I want to define the same margin for everything and avoid the margins from summing up, but this is also useful on horizontal margins, and those can't collapse!

### **Does anyone knows why margins are allowed to collapse?**

Answer (score -1):

Imagine you have 2 HTML boxes. The first one has a margin-bottom of let's say 30px and the second one a margin-top of 20px. After rules of collapsing margins have been applied we have a margin of 30px (not 50px) between these two boxes  . This is because no addition of both margins takes place but the maximum of both is applied. This behavior is called collapsing margins and does only apply to vertical margins.

Oftentimes it is a good behavior but collapsing margins can be annoying, too.

Comment: This doesn't really answer why.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, I already understand how they work, I want to understand WHY this was selected by the W3C to work like this.